# Excel built in for "active sheet"?

Tags: excel

I'm a director of systems and infrastructure at a university and trying to use excel as a budget projection tool.  I have a workbook of "quotes"...for example:

- sheet1 is a quote from dell for 22 servers
- sheet2 is a quote from vmware for 100 vsphere licenses
- sheet3 is a quote from cisco for 2 Nexus 7000 switches
- sheet4 is a quote from cisco for 4 c6807 switches
- sheet5 is a quote from cisco for 2 asa5585x firewalls
- sheet6 is a quote from Compellent for a 100TB SSD SAN, etc.

I currently have 307 sheets that comprise my 5 year budget outlook.  The higher the sheet's number the less firm the projection.  The first sheet is and will always be an Executive Summary, the second sheet is and will always be a detailed summary.  All other sheets have the following in common.

1. Quote or Estimate #
2. Hardware Cost
3. Software Software Cost
4. Support Cost
5. Advanced/Professional Services Cost
6. Shipping Cost
7. Discount

The kicker is that they're never in the same cell's across sheets.

---

**What I've been frantically searching for is the following:**

1. A way to change Excel's default name scope from global to local
2. A built in expandable variable for active sheet

---

What I'm wanting to do seems so simple.  I want to click on sheet 3 who's name is "vSphere 5 DR Stretch Cluster", click on the cell with the Estimate # (C5 for this sheet), click in the "Name Box" and type either:

1. quote
2. ./!quote or $!quote or ANYTHING OTHER THAN'vSphere 5 DR Stretch Cluster!quote'...or god forbid using the "Formulas > Define Name" wizard

---

Then click on sheet 4 who's name is "vSphere 5 EntPlus Licensing", click on the cell with the Estimate # (A2 for this sheet), click in the "Name Box" and type either:

1. quote
2. .`pwd`!quote or $PWD!quote or ANYTHING OTHER THAN 'vSphere 5 EntPlus Licensing'!quote...or god forbid using the "Formulas > Define Name" wizard

etc etc and for all 7 commons across all 39585943938494 gazillion sheets.  I've got about 30 min under my belt of asking the google machine and i'm ice cold.

Please tell me excel has an super quick, super short expandable built in variable (like . or ./ or $$ or ^) for active sheet.

Or if someone know's of a better tool then excel I could use for this effort, please feel free to share.

Comment: "super short expandable built in variable (like . or ./ or $$ or ^) for active sheet." you mean [ActiveSheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174742%28v=office.11%29.aspx)?

Comment: Tried that, no joy...plus it's not that short.  ActiveSheet!quote gave me a reference validity error while 'vSphere 5 EntPlus Licensing'!quote works fine.

Comment: tried that too, and it worked until the next sheet...excel insists on making ALL names entered in the "Name Box" globally scoped.

Comment: ok.. my last suggestion.. Try just using an `!` so for range A1 use `!A1`

Comment: You can edit and control the things in the Names Manager.  Have you tried that or is that too onerous?

Comment: Sam - tried that too, reference validity error

Comment: RB - that works but it's wicked slow, prone to error and emotionally torturous...however it is how I'm slugging it out now and i'm about in tears

Comment: @user30772 OK, hang on, I have something around here that can do it...

Comment: @user30772 Oops, very important, what version of Excel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42145/discussion-between-user30772-and-rbarryyoung)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have a macro that can do this.  Here's how to install it:

- press Alt+F8 to bring up the Macros dialog.
- Type in "DefineLocalName" in the "Macro name:" textbox, then click the [Create] button.
- In the VBA editor, Copy and paste the following code in-between the `Sub DefineLocalName` and `End Sub` lines:

.

```
' get the current selection
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Selected", vbOKOnly, "Cannot Define Local Name"
    Exit Sub
End If

' get the current worksheet
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = rng.Worksheet

' get the name to define
Dim sNam As String
sNam = InputBox("Enter the Name to Define for this Sheet:", "Define Local Name")
If sNam = "" Then Exit Sub

' define a name local to this worksheet
wks.Names.Add sNam, rng.Address
```

.

- Use the "file" menu to "Close and return to Excel"
- back in Excel, press Alt+F8 to bring up the Macros dialog again.
- Select "DefineLocalName", then click the [Options] button.  Then enter a letter to define a shortcut key (I use "k", becuase I never us the usual Ctrl+k function).

Now you should be able to define worksheet-local names simply by selecting a range and type Ctrl+K.  It will ask you for a name and then assign then name locally to the currently selected range.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: FWIW, I hate this always global defaulting for Names also.  It causes a lot of problems in other more complex operations.

Comment: Yeah, defaulting to global is so 1980's microsoft.  It works, the formatting of the answer was jacked the first time I tried.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but with a little tweaking could I create 7 macros, one for each of my 7 commons, then just ctrl+q for local.quote, ctrl+h for local.hardware, ctrl+s for local.software, etc?

that would be epic

Comment: Correct again, that worked wonderfully RB, thank you.  Is there a way for me to give you credit for the excellent answer(s) and work?

Comment: actually it isn't working, your macro creates the reference `="$B$2"`  while I think it should be `'VMware Servers'!"$B$2"`

Comment: @user30772 I think that may just be how the Name Manager displays things.  AFAIK, it only displays the sheet name in the "Refers To" for Global names.  Local names don't have a sheet name in the Refers_To, but do have their "Scope" set to the local worksheet instead of to the workbook.  Try this: Go to another sheet and enter `='VMWare Servers'!YourName` into a cell.  It should work (I just tried it on mine and it does work for me).  If this is not what you wanted, then let me know.